# R function to remove rows containing numerically similar data

Tags: r

I have a number of dataframes containing time vs concentration data spanning the length of some trial event.

The concentration is steady state, then an area of change occurs, then the data returns to steady state.

I'm looking to filter out the steady state data so as only to include the area of change.

I was thinking it might be possible to remove data points that are numerically similar (using a % tolerance) to the preceding entry in the dataframe, but I'm not sure how to go about this. Could anyone lend me a hand?

A sample of the dataframe can be found below:

```
 head(data)
                 date       NO
1 2020-01-01 12:46:51 1042.034
2 2020-01-01 12:46:53 1042.034
3 2020-01-01 12:46:55 1042.034
4 2020-01-01 12:46:57 1042.034
5 2020-01-01 12:46:59 1043.612
6 2020-01-01 12:47:01 1043.612
```

Comment: It is much easier to provide sample data (esp with embedded spaces) by using `dput(head(data))`, as it gives it in an unambiguous (R) format.

Comment: Using an absolute difference, `data[c(TRUE, diff(data$NO) > 0.01),]`?

Comment: Or a 0.1% percentage change, `data[c(TRUE, diff(data$NO) / data$NO[-1] > 0.001),]`

Comment: @r2evansThat's a 0.1% change.

Comment: Rui yup, I caught it (and edited before your comment came in :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
reldiff <- function(x, fill = NA) c(fill, diff(x)/x[-1])

reldiff(data$NO)
#[1]          NA 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.001512056
#[6] 0.000000000

reldiff(data$NO, fill = 0)
#[1] 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.001512056
#[6] 0.000000000
```

Then, this can be used to get where the difference is smaller/bigger than a certain threshold.

```
i <- reldiff(data$NO, fill = 0) > 0.001
data[i, ]
#                 date       NO
#5 2020-01-01 12:46:59 1043.612
```

**Data**

```
data <- read.table(text = "
date       NO
1 '2020-01-01 12:46:51' 1042.034
2 '2020-01-01 12:46:53' 1042.034
3 '2020-01-01 12:46:55' 1042.034
4 '2020-01-01 12:46:57' 1042.034
5 '2020-01-01 12:46:59' 1043.612
6 '2020-01-01 12:47:01' 1043.612
", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you! I found this works better when changed to 
```reldiff <- function(x, fill = NA) c(fill, diff(x))
i <- abs(reldiff(decay_n$NO, fill = 0)) > 10```
as the data varies in magnitude significantly thus using a percentage tolerance actually isn't the best way to filter (my mistake).